# Viewbix players count toward Youtube viewcounts. I can't find any others that do. Why, exactly

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, html5-video, jwplayer, youtube-javascript-api

I've asked related questions, and no one seems to know anything about this.  Answers on the net all say no custom player will count, but this is not true.  Viewbix does, and I want to understand why.  As near as I can tell, none of the views from jw, mediaelement.js, jplayer, voo, lead, covert, herocaster, or any of the others count toward yt view counts.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is what I've been able to dig up.

Generally available info says play needs to be using yt's native play button and not auto-started

Is it that viewbix is simply wrapping the regular youtube player rather than accessing through js api?  Is that what they're doing that is different than voo, jw, covert, lead, and any of the countless other players whose views do not count?

Their embed code looks like this:

which is different from what I see with other players in that it is referring to an html file (which has js on it) as opposed to referring to a js file hosted somewhere.

Anyone have insights here?

Comment: why you say that custom player don't count the view ? any source ?

Comment: Youtube's own documentation, JW player developer's forum responses, and a number of threads I've come across where people have tested and/or asked developers about the topic.  It's not one source.  It's more like a couple dozen.  Getting down to the nitty-gritty about EXACTLY what makes it count or not is a bit trickier.  It's not clear if ANYTHING involving the js api is out, or if you enable the api but initial play button is via their chromeless player...  It's a lot more involved than it appears at first glance, and the only people I've seen give answers have given incorrect summations.

Comment: Do you have an example of Viewbix that does this? I have never heard of a 3rd party player that does this.

Comment: I'll see if I can set one up on a channel with no views for a demo.  Don't think I can embed vid here, but will look into and post somewhere.  I thought it was incorrect too... like they were claiming something they couldn't deliver.  Upon looking, I think it comes down to them using the actual youtube player then wrapping and overlaying it, so the play is initiated by the YT player.  Still haven't verified the count going up, but that seems to make sense and fit YT's description of what counts.  After a little experimentation, it would seem that any play initiated via js api is null.